# How to demonstrate "Things aren't always as they appear"?

Tags: experimental-physics, education

My task is to create an experiment (for middle school through College Freshman) that demonstrates that things aren't always as they appear. (Note: NOT Homework -- TV Production company)
My first draft uses clock drives. The hands of the clock move at a 12:1 ratio. The gears inside are all the same. Take the gears out, put them back in, clock no longer works with a 12:1 ratio. Even though the gears are all the same, there is a specific order to them. You can't just change them willy-nilly and still have it work.

The problem: it's rather boring and most people don't get it.

Are there any simple, ordinary things that you have observed that would make a great example of concept?

The moral is supposed to be two-fold:

1. Don't judge a book by it's cover (to use a cliche')
2. Things work through a synergy of multiple parts. Changing one could have deleterious effects on the entire system
3. Examine & Study the issue before trying to change it

This production is aimed at getting students more interested in STEM through fun & creativity. This demonstration is a prelude to the scientific method -- analyze first, reserve judgement until the very end!
I have a few ideas, however I thought I'd solicit some experts on unique ideas.
How would you demonstrate this principle?
TIA

Comment: There is a demonstration on youtube of a piece of aluminum foil enclosed in a wax block. Just by turning the block and observing light passing through it, it is quite difficult to figure out what exactly is going on with this block. This demonstrates basically the same as what you want to show. I'll add the link later tonight.

Comment: The paraffin block paradox is a classic. What about dropping objects through a thick copper tube (maybe measuring fall speed being independent of mass), where the odd one out is the magnet that gets slowed down by eddy currents?

Comment: middle school is probably still young enough that they can be baffled that heavy things don't fall faster than light things, but I guess it doesn't address your point 2.

Comment: It's not really physics, but there is an interesting demonstration of queuing theory and nonlinear business systems done in management classes, where you “hire” your class into “jobs” rolling dice to move products through an assembly line, the nonlinearity coming from stations being unable to produce output if they do not have enough input. Usually everyone falls short of the monthly goal and you can keep tabs on people who did not roll the dice well and thus got “fired.” https://public.wsu.edu/~engrmgmt/holt/em530/Docs/DiceGames.htm

Comment: The key lesson there being that your students will appreciate a story and an interactive game.